# This mysql code produces a syntax error and im not sure why

Tags: mysql

```
select EMP_LNAME  from Employee where EMP_DOB -0 > 19700000 LEFT OUTER JOIN Store ON Employee.STORE_CODE = Store.STORE_CODE NATURAL JOIN Region where REGION_DESCRIPT = 'East';
```

this code causes a 1024 error in mysql and i am not sure why. any ideas?

Comment: check for if you have read access to file that shown in error ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your syntax is wrong. The syntax must be `select ... from ... join ... on ... where` Try this:

```
select EMP_LNAME  from Employee  LEFT OUTER JOIN Store ON Employee.STORE_CODE = Store.STORE_CODE NATURAL JOIN Region where EMP_DOB -0 > 19700000 and REGION_DESCRIPT = 'East';
```